# Updating values inside <script> block with Meteor dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, dynamic-variables

I am building an application with Meteor that is using a progress bar defined in javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
    var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(percentbar, {
      strokeWidth: 4,
      easing: 'easeInOut',
      duration: 1400,
      color: '#ED6A5A',
      trailColor: '#eee',
      trailWidth: 1,
      svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
      text: {
        style: {
          color: '#999',
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '0',
          top: '30px',
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
          transform: null
        },
        autoStyleContainer: false
      },
      from: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
      to: {color: '#7eed5a'},
      step: (state, bar) => {
        bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
        bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      }
    });
    bar.animate((Session.get('vready') * 1.0)/Session.get('vtotal'));  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
</script>
```

I want the progress bar to re-render with the correct percentage when the session variables accessed in the last lines change. However, it only renders once and does not update when changes are made to the session variables. Is there a way to re-trigger the animation of the percent bar when the session variables change?

P.S. I have tried defining the percent bar code in my .js as a helper to the template instead of in the .html file, but I get an exception every time and the bar does not render at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a better case for `Tracker.autorun()`

1. Initialize your progress bar in `Template.onRendered()`
2. Create a session variable that tracks current progress
3. Update the svg in the `Tracker.autorun()`

js:

```
Tracker.autorun(()=>{
  bar.setText(Math.round(Session.get('currentValue') * 100) + ' %');
  bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
});
```

You don't really use `<script>` tags in Meteor. Instead you attach your js to template events and objects.

Comment: I don't think this is an option. the way the library this bar uses works it would seem that it creates the HTML when the bar is initialized. When I move it to the onCreate method it crashes similar to how it crashes when it is a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helpers with `reactive-var` for this purpose.

Example code:

Put the following code in `onRendered` callback

```
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
    var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(percentbar, {
      strokeWidth: 4,
      easing: 'easeInOut',
      duration: 1400,
      color: '#ED6A5A',
      trailColor: '#eee',
      trailWidth: 1,
      svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
      text: {
        style: {
          // Text color.
          // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
          color: '#999',
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '0',
          top: '30px',
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
          transform: null
        },
        autoStyleContainer: false
      },
      from: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
      to: {color: '#7eed5a'},
      step: (state, bar) => {
        bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
        bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
      }

console.log((progressBarValue.get() * 1.0)/Session.get('vtotal'));
    bar.animate((progressBarValue.get() * 1.0)/Session.get('vtotal'));
    });
```

Put the following code in `onCreated` callback

```
var progressBarValue;
Template.home.onCreated(function (){
    progressBarValue=new ReactiveVar(0);

});
```

Set the new value for Progress Bar using an `event` block with this line:

`progressBarValue.set(*value*);`

This will make the progress bar reactive.

Alternatively, with `session` you can use the `Tracker.autorun` to do the job.